# Using filestream within a button click event in ms visual c++

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I know that you have to include the fstream library in order to use. Let's say I have a windows form project in visual c++ named sample_project. And of course that would have a main source file named sample_project.cpp.

I have placed

```
include <fstream>
```

on the sample_project.cpp file but calling the filestream functions in the button click event on my form still does not work. This is probably basic stuff that I am missing here but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for certain, because you forgot to post the code from your button click event handler where you try to call the filestream functions, but my guess is that you've forgotten to qualify the function calls with the appropriate namespace.

The functions defined in that header file are in the `std` namespace, so you would have to write:

```
std::fstream
```

Or add a using directive to the top of your code file:

```
using namespace std;
```

Also, I assume you just had problems with the code formatting feature, but make sure that your include statement *actually* looks like this, noting the `#` sign and the lack of space around the angle brackets:

```
#include <fstream>
```

Remember that a Windows Forms project targets the .NET Framework, and is designed to facilitate interoperability between native and managed code. If you intended to write pure, unmanaged C++ code, you create a console or Win32 application, instead. And if you don't need the specific functionality provided by  `fstream.h`, you could investigate using the standard file manipulation classes included with the .NET Framework. They're not quite as powerful, but they are more than adequate in the majority of cases, and far simpler to use for a beginning programmer.

Comment: I won't downvote you for that last paragraph, because the rest of your answer is both good and relevant.  But it's holding me back from voting you up.  Mixing managed and native code is the emphasis of C++/CLI.  Maybe he has a library that needs to be passed an `fstream` object.  If you're going to use the (crippled) .NET classes for everything, might as well use C#.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, that's very true. But given the question, I didn't think it was very likely that he was trying to do managed-native interop. Maybe I'm reading too much into the question, it's hard to say. More than anything, I think there is a lot of confusion surrounding C++/CLI, and I've seen far too many people who are new to Visual Studio and want to start using C++ create a Windows Forms application by mistake. I suppose that should have been the direction I took, instead.